# How to compress C++ code?

Tags: c++, compression

I need to compress some C++ code. The exe must be as compressed as possible. It's for Zero Robotics and the codesize usage now is 139% and I need to reduce this. Are there tools to compress the code?

Comment: Do you want to compress the size of the .cpp source file or the executable file or reduce the memory usage of the program?

Comment: What's taking up too much space? Is the _executable_ too big or is the _memory used at runtime_ too much?

Comment: And if it's the _executable_, which operating system is it for?

Comment: I think you used the wrong verb. To me the answer is: "use a lamptorch in front of your screen"...

Comment: Changed "light" to "compress" and fixed a few other things. If your question is really about memory usage, then "compress" isn't really the right word. It's still not exactly clear what needs to be compressed - the code? the exe file? both? Also, to help you improve your English, "to light something" means to set it on fire. "To light up something" is to illuminate it with a light. "To lighten something" is to make it lighter (weigh less) or make the colour of it lighter.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to *improve* it.

Comment: Sorry but i'm not english so I don't speack well. I need to compress the executable.

Comment: If you need to compress the executable use a packer. But then you declare elsewhere that you can't use a packer. Which means that you don't want to compress the executable. You want to write your program so that less code is emitted by the compiler. Well, go to work on your program then. Only you can do that. Only you can see your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all you can do is edit your source code, the only way to reduce the size of your executable is to find ways to consolidate stuff.

Things to look out for:

- Find dead code and resources. Delete all functions/methods/variable that are not used.
- Find duplicate code and data. For example, if you have a function/method that is copy&pasted into several files, refactor your code so that you only need one version of it.
- Maybe try to reduce the amount of string constants and other resources you're using.
- If you're using any 3rd party code/libraries, try if you can do without it or if there's a more lightweight alternative.

There is no automated way to do this I'm aware of. You really have to look through your source yourself and clean it up by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you want to reduce the executable file size, you can check your compiler options to reduce the obj size. If you are using GCC, check the manual for the options `-s` and `-Os`.

Comment: I can't. The compiler is online, I can edit only the code, not the command for compile it.

Comment: @TheDeveloper: Can you modify the _executable_, that is the file that the compiler produced (like an .exe file)? Or can you only edit the _source code_? You really need to be more precise and provide more information.

Comment: I can edit the source and I need to compress the exe.

Comment: @TheDeveloper: I repeat the vital part of my questions that you ignored: _Can you modify the executable?_ Can you run a command that will modify the exe? For example, can you run `strip` or `upx` on the final exe?

Answer (score 1):

A few years ago, i used the upx packer for executables, which compresses an exe-file.

< [1]: http://upx.sourceforge.net/>

Maybe, this is what  you are looking for.